# Missing "StructuredAlgorithms"in the installation

Tags: algorithm

I typed the following

```
array = SymmetrizedArray[{{1, 3} -> a, {2, 2} -> b}, {3, 3}, 
  Symmetric[All]]
array["StructuredAlgorithms"]
```

which should give me the list of algorithms supported for SymmetrizedArray, according to the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SymmetrizedArray.html) (properties and relations). My list is returning empty, I don't understand why. I am on version 13.3.1, of the student's license and the last update on this link was in version 12.

Comment: on `14.0.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (December 13, 2023) ` it works well.

Comment: Also works perfectly on `14.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)`

Comment: You are linking the documentation for 14.0 while you are using 13.1. I do not see this documented in the same page for 13.1.

Comment: Well, I don't have local documentation so I always go to the web and the last update in "History" is marked as 2020, version 12.1. Are you looking at the local documentation? BTW, I have 13.3.1 in macOS M1 and Linux x86, in both cases this example gives empty lists.

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong – it just looks like there were no special algorithms implemented for `SymmetrizedArray` in 13.3 yet (but they are in 14.0). But there are algorithms for other structures in 13.3, for example try `LowerTriangularMatrix[{{2, 0}, {1, -5}}]["StructuredAlgorithms"]`

Comment: Of course, that could be the case. However, I was expecting that, in this case, the online documentation would warn you with "last update version 14" or something.

Comment: @Felipe, I certainly agree with you. However, it looks like the WRI is marking the changes only if they appear in the top blue usage section or under the Details section. See for example [`NSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolve.html) – it was updated in v14, but if you click on _UPDATED, show changes_, only the changes in the top of the page will be marked with yellow, even though there was obviously also a change in the _Options_ section (added `MaxRoots`).

Comment: @Domen I see, but even If they don't show all, if you look at history at the end of NSolve they are still marking the last update as 2023 (14.0), while the SymmmetrizedArray page is 2020 (12.1). Maybe there was an update and they forgot to mark it in the web page. Otherwise, I don't see why version 13.3.1 would lack these algorithms.

Comment: I did the update to version 14 and it is there in fact. But at any case the structured algorithms are rather slow. My intention was to use then to take tensor products of numeric tensors which are totally symmetric. I imagined that this algorithms would be faster, but a Simple test with rank2 arrays shows that just using packed arrays is way faster. But perhaps this should be another question.

Comment: @Felipe, what I am trying to say is that it _looks like_ they mark the update only if this update is present in the beginning of the documentation (which is true for `NSolve` but not for `SymmetrizedArray`).